# Printing atoi value of an uninitialised array

Tags: c, arrays, atoi

Simple question, below is my code. The number my compiler returns is 4219296. My question is: why? What is my code doing here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
char array[];

int main()
{

atoi(array);
printf("%d \n", array);


return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your code does not even compile! Also what you get could be the adress of the first element from your array.

Comment: `char array[];`...either initialize or use a size.

Comment: You should read about [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because that's what you're experiencing.

Comment: print address of array as int.

Comment: The code compiles for me, but with warnings. Your atoi(array) line is ending up doing nothing. It makes an integer from the array but, because you do not store the result anywhere, it just gets thrown away immediately.

Comment: BTW `array` has been initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `atoi` returns the converted value. This value needs to be stored. Here in the above program you are not storing the returned value. So there is no effect on the array variable.

Printing the array in decimal format gives you the address of the array. The program shall print the same value even without the `atoi` function. To confirm try this:

```
//...
printf("%d \n", array);
atoi(array);
printf("%d \n", array);
```

Output remains same.

Answer (score 0):

Here that is printing the address of the starting position in of your array. If you use 
a pointer you will get the value of that.

```
  printf(" %d \n",*array);
```

Here atoi is doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong, you want to convert a `string` containg a *numberic value* into an integer.

In your code, because of `char array[];` `atoi()` will face [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You need to pass some valid address to the API.

Also, instead of using `atoi()`, use the safer counterpart [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol).

Check the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char ip[ ] = "12345";
    char *err;

    long int retval;

    retval = strtol(ip, &err, 0);
    printf("strng format : %s, int format %ld\n", ip, retval);


    return 0;
}
```

O/P

> [sourav@broadsword temp]$ ./a.out
>
> string format : 12345, int format 12345

Also, if you change the `ip` to someting like `char ip[ ] = "12A45";`, then the o/p will look like

> [sourav@broadsword temp]$ ./a.out
> string format : 12A45, int format 12

Comment: @Gopi as you please. :-)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY sir, is it because in that case `array` is _assumed_ to have one element?

Comment: It is effective as a C object. This result of `atoi(array)` is undefined because `atoi` cannot be converted to a numerical value from `""`.